# How to make WinBUGS close when “Trap” occurs

Tags: r, winbugs, r2winbugs

This is just the same question I posted in 
[CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/89128/41481), where some considered it *off topic*. So, I reproduce it here:

I'm using `R2WinBUGS` to process several datasets in WinBUGS in "batch mode" from R. Occasionally traps occur, mainly due to bad parameters (I guess), and I managed to avoid the whole R script to stop using `try`, and to retry automatically. Yet, when this happens, I have to manually close WinBUGS in order to let the R script go on.

Is there a way to make WinBUGS exit automatically as soon as a trap happens?